# Magento 2 error on an overriden constructor

Tags: magento2, module, third-party-module

I have 2 custom modules installed, when opening a front end of a module1, i get error related to module2, this is the error

```
Argument 4 passed to VendorName\Module2\Block\Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::__construct() must be of the type array, null given, called in /var/www/html/magento2.3.1/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 117 [] []
```

In front end i got this error

```
Missing required argument $data of VendorName\Module2\Block\Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render.
```

As you see the module2 overrides Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render.php class

On VendorName/Module2/Block/Magento/Framework/Pricing/Render.php

```
namespace VendorName\Module2\Block\Magento\Framework\Pricing;

use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Amount\AmountInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\PriceInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\SaleableInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Layout;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use VendorName\Module2\Helper\Data;

/**
 * Class Render
 * @package VendorName\Module2\Block\Magento\Framework\Pricing
*/
class Render extends \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render
{

 * @var \VendorName\Module2\Helper\Data
 */
private $dataHelper;

/**
 * Render constructor.
 * @param \VendorName\Module2\Helper\Data $dataHelper
 * @param Template\Context $context
 * @param Layout $priceLayout
 * @param array $data
 */

public function __construct(Data $dataHelper, Template\Context $context, Layout $priceLayout, array $data)
{
    $this->dataHelper = $dataHelper;
    parent::__construct($context, $priceLayout, $data);
}

}
```

I searched for the call to render class on Module 1 i found it here
in venorName1/Module1/Helper/Catalog.php

```
namespace VendorName1\Module1\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime;

class Catalog extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
private $date;
private $helper;
private $renderer;
private $block;
private $linkFactory;
private $optionBlock;
private $priceFormat;
private $imageHelper;
private $coreRegistry;
private $blockFactory;
private $productLinks;
private $priceCurrency;
private $pricingHelper;
private $objectManager;
private $catalogHelper;
private $storeInterface;
private $productFactory;
private $downloadHelper;
private $configurableBlock;
private $catalogProductHelper;
private $eachProduct = [];

public function __construct(
    DateTime $date,
    \Webkul\Pos\Helper\Data $helper,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data $catalogHelper,
    \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render $renderer,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template $block,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $dir,
    \Webkul\Pos\Block\Configurable $configurableBlock,
    \Magento\Downloadable\Helper\File $downloadHelper,
    \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data $priceFormat,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data $pricingHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $catalogProductHelper,
    \Magento\Downloadable\Model\LinkFactory $linkFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options $optionBlock,
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockFactory $blockFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeInterface,
    \Magento\Downloadable\Block\Catalog\Product\Links $productLinks,
    \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency
) {
    $this->date           = $date;
    $this->helper         = $helper;
    $this->renderer       = $renderer;
    $this->block          = $block;
    $this->_baseDir       = $dir->getPath("media");
    $this->optionBlock    = $optionBlock;
    $this->priceFormat    = $priceFormat;
    $this->blockFactory   = $blockFactory;
    $this->coreRegistry   = $coreRegistry;
    $this->imageHelper    = $imageHelper;
    $this->priceCurrency  = $priceCurrency;
    $this->pricingHelper  = $pricingHelper;
    $this->objectManager  = $objectManager;
    $this->catalogHelper  = $catalogHelper;
    $this->productLinks   = $productLinks;
    $this->linkFactory    = $linkFactory;
    $this->downloadHelper = $downloadHelper;
    $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
    $this->storeInterface = $storeInterface;
    $this->configurableBlock = $configurableBlock;
    $this->catalogProductHelper = $catalogProductHelper;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
}
```

How can i fix this error or debug it?

Comment: In your module 1, are you trying to call your customer Render class or the default Magento framework one?

Comment: @mlunt it's  the Magento Framework \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render $renderer, on constructor $this->renderer = $renderer;
I tried to call the Module 2 Render class but always same error

Comment: It may be looking for your new instance from module 1 because of the dependency inheritance. I’d put an echo statement in your module 1 class to confirm.

Comment: Put an cho on venorName1/Module1/Helper/Catalog.php  or the page front end controller where i have the error?

Comment: In the module itself

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the generated directory -

```
rm -rf generated/
```

Comment: I got the same error